# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ckeditor', how do i solve this?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-ckeditor

I have ckeditor installed inside venv. In my setting, I also added ckeditor and ckeditor_uploader in my setting. I also added to requirements.txt. But nothing seems to be working. Still getting [the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdVhb.png)`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ckeditor'`

the printing error in my terminal

```
docs        |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], 
package, level)
docs        |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 
1030, in _gcd_import
docs        |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 
1007, in _find_and_load
docs        |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, 
in _find_and_load_unlocked

docs        | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ckeditor'

docs        | 
docs        | Command exited with exit code: 2
docs        | The server will continue serving the build 
folder, but the contents being served are no longer in sync 
with the documentation sources. Please fix the cause of the 
error above or press Ctrl+C to stop the server.
docs        | [I 210801 18:55:41 server:335] Serving on 
http://0.0.0.0:7000
docs        | [I 210801 18:55:41 handlers:62] Start watching 
changes
docs        | [I 210801 18:55:41 handlers:64] Start detecting 
changes
^CGracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Stopping docs     ... done
Stopping postgres ... done
(env) diev@diev:~/test_project$ 


Here is my setting.py

DJANGO_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    # "django.contrib.humanize", # Handy template tags
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.forms",
]
THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    "crispy_forms",
    "allauth",
    "allauth.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount",
    "rest_framework",
    "rest_framework.authtoken",
    "corsheaders",
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
]

LOCAL_APPS = [
    "test_project.users.apps.UsersConfig",
    "test_project.core.apps.CoreConfig",
    "test_project.cart.apps.CartConfig",
    # Your stuff: custom apps go here
]

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + LOCAL_APPS

CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = 
'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js'

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'images/'
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = "pillow"

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
'default': {
    'toolbar': None,
    },
}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('_ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
]
```

models.py

```
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField


class About(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    about_text = RichTextUploadingField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

Comment: `ckeditor` and `ckeditor_uploader` in your setting are in `THIRD_PARTY_APPS`. How have you included in `INSTALLED_APPS` ..?? Please add `INSTALLED_APPS` as well in the question...??

Comment: thanks, i'm using cookiecutter-django configuration you can check the question i have edited

Comment: it would be useful if you could show us how the error appears: if you launch your app in a terminal, could you copy the content of your terminal (at least from the command you run to the error itself) ? Or if you launch it from an IDE, maybe a screenshot of your IDE when the error appears.

Comment: appreciate, i have added the screenshot and also the printing error in terminal

Comment: Is ckeditor exists in requirement.txt ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running 'manage.py collectstatic'?
Try installing it step by step from the docs:
https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation

Comment: i have tried manage.py collectstatic, trough wing the same error , i think the problem is with my docker configuration because same code, working perfect without docker

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and my problem ended up being that I had forgotten to update my requirements.txt file before I pushed the git master to Heroku.  Once I ran pip freeze > requirements.txt and then updated the git master with the new requirements.txt file I had no issues running git push heroku master.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case I realized I hadn't installed the ckeditor package inside my virtual enviroment, but only globally. Make sure you install the ckeditor package with your virtual environment previously activated:

In Windows:

```
.\virt_env\Scripts\activate
```

(Where `virt_env` is the name of your virtual environment.)

The name of the virtual environment should appear inside parenthesis at the command prompt. Then you install the package there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I figured out that I didn't add comma at the end of my 'ckeditor' in my `setting.py` of the project.

After adding the comma, it worked for me.